# How to create a global function from within a scope

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, closures, youtube-iframe-api

I have a function such as this one:

```
function CreateYoutubePlayer(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
}
```

The loaded script requires a global function called `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`. How do I create this function within the above function so that it is globally accessible.

Comment: `window.func = function(){}` or just `func = function(){}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can attach the function to the global window object:

```
function CreateYoutubePlayer(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo) {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` outside of the `CreateYoutubePlayer` function as an empty variable. This will create a global variable, and you can then populate that function within `CreateYoutubePlayer`

Comment: I want to avoid that if possible.